# Log4j2.xml configuration in web.xml. IllegalArgumentException - uri is not absolute

Tags: java, web-applications, classpath, web.xml, log4j2

Before adding **context-param and Log4jConfigListener** for `Log4j2`, I had all logs listed in **catalina.out** file.

So now, I'm trying to configure `log4j` for my web application.

In **`web.xml`**, I've added necessary configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>etl-service</display-name>

    <!-- Support for Spring -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>myprofile</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


</web-app>
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" strict="true" name="XMLConfigTest"
               packages="">         

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFileDebug" fileName="/local/deploy/logs/debug.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/etl-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                                 immediateFlush="false"
                                 append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="/local/deploy/logs/info.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/etl-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                                 immediateFlush="false"
                                 append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <!--<Async name="AsyncConsole">-->
        <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console"/>-->
        <!--</Async>-->
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root  level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFileDebug" level="DEBUG"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" level="INFO"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"  level="TRACE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But for now I have the **following error:**

```
ERROR Unable to access WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
```

Maybe someone already faced with such issue. Also I've tried 
instead adding `/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` use `classpath*:log4j.xml`

And had an **error** `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in schema name at 9 index: classpath*:log4j.xml`

**UPDATE:**
We need to add just descriptor file name and it works.

```
<context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
            <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
```

But issue remineds logs listed in catalina.out file. Not in my log4j files.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to specify the config location when it's the default.

Comment: what do you mean by config? what is the default location?

Comment: The default location is at the root of the classpath. Where you have it. By "config" I mean "configuration". Stay safe, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, already found the issue. I've added <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value> without any directories. And I thougth that,s it. But now another issue.  All my logs goes to catalina.out but not into my log4j files.

Comment: Maybe we should add some configuration into tomcat/logs/logging.properties

Comment: Please post your full log4j2.xml so we can help investigate why your log messages go to Catalina.log. What version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: of course, please check log4j2.xml

Answer (score 14):

You did not specify Spring version and Servler version..

Since Spring 4.2.1 the `Log4jConfigListener` is deprecated.

Let's assume you are using Spring version 4.2.1(+), Servlet 3.0(+) and Log4j2. Now all you have to do is to:

1. add new dependency [**log4j-web**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web),
2. a) put **log4j2**.xml file into WEB-INF folder **OR** b) put your log4j2 configuration into classpath and define `log4jConfiguration` context param within web.xml with configuration file specified.

So you don't have to specify any listener at all.

Here comes the [Log4j2's documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) which describes it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that your log4j configuration file name is log4j**2**.xml, so trying to point to log4j.xml is quite pointless. 
Please find that unless using servlet container below 2.5, your log4j may be configurable by itself.

First of all, verify if your log4j configuration is correct. Start container with `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` pointing to your log4j2.xml. You can also add debug with `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=debug`

Using tomcat, edit your ${catalina.home}/bin/setenv.sh (or .bat, if using windows) and add it to JAVA_OPTS variable.

If your log4j will start logging both to file and console, try removing both:

> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
>     <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

as well as:

> ```
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>
>         org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
>     </listener-class>
> </listener>
> ```

Spring is based on log4j 1.x, so add dependencies to your build (maven example):

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where `log4j-1.2-api` is compatibility api, and `log4j-web` is web application support.

Answer (score 0):

See the source code of org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener. It expects a system property by name "log4jConfigLocation". This property should hold the location of the file if it's in classpath then its value should be classpath:/logs/log4j2.xml. If it's a file resource then it should be file://Users/logs/log4j2.xml.
So add a context parm in web.xml. 
For example:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file://Users/logs/log4j2.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Also note that spring's Log4jConfigListener is works with log4j 1.x version.